InfluxDB Flux - filter tag names by string
Hi I have some tags with similar names that I would like to filter by name.
I have some with the word “return” in them, I don't want to use them, but the tags with the word “active” should be used.
I have created it in a table to illustrate what I mean.



aba_return_active
ab_active
ab_return
ab
aba_active




Cell 1
Cell 2
Cell 3
Cell 4
Cell 5



After the filter it should look like this.



ab_active
aba_active




Cell 2
Cell 5



And is it possible to search for multiple strings in the query?
e.g. “active”, “PV” and “work”
Many thanks for your help!
Kind regards

You can use regular expressions in keep function so as to keep only columns that you need.
See an example for your test data:
import "array"

array.from(rows:[{  aba_return_active : "Cell 1",   
                    ab_active : "Cell 2",   
                    ab_return : "Cell 3",   
                    ab : "Cell 4",  
                    aba_active : "Cell 5"}])
|> keep(fn: (column) => column =~ /active/)

